# About my GPU- is it integrated?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu, devices

Here is my grephics card output on `lspci | grep VGA`:
NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
I did not buy my computer, but I heard, so it has integrated graphics card. I want to know- is this integrated graphics card and if so, how do I found it out without opening my computer box?

Answer (score 0):

Motherboards very rarely have Nvidia integrated Graphics but the easiest way to find out would be to look at the back of the desktop and check if the monitor inputs are directly connected to the motherboard. This can easily be spotted by looking for a HDMI, DVI, DisplayPort, or VGA connector next to other inputs such as Ethernet, audio connectors and USB ports. If it is a card then it would be installed in one of the PCI slots usually situated near the bottom of the tower.

Admittedly because this answer doesn't really mention Ubuntu in any way it is sort of invalid in the context but it should still answer the question.

Comment: My computer has 2 VGA slots, and my cable is pluged in bottom one(horizontal)...

Comment: If it is plugged into the bottom VGA slot it is using the GeForce GT 610 PCI graphics card. Additionally the other VGA slot would be for the computers integrated graphics.

Comment: Yeah! So I hear good news- it is not integrated

Comment: Like I said your computer likely has an integrated graphics chip but it isn't in use right now as you are using the Nvidia graphics card instead.

Comment: So I have 2 GPUs? Integrated and my current?

Comment: But what is GF119?

Comment: You have a graphics chip on the motherboard and one in the PCI slot but in most cases you can only use one at a time. Some newer motherboards allow you to use both integrated and PCI graphics in tandem so you can use the inputs on the integrated chip as well as the PCI card. For example, my motherboard has DisplayPort and HDMI and my graphics card has HDMI, DVI, and VGA inputs but if I enable an option in my UFEI I can use all of these inputs to connect 5 monitors but sadly I haven't got this feature to work on Linux yet. GF119 is the Fabrication process and transistors used in manufacture.

Comment: So currently I use PCI, which is faster, right?

Comment: Commonly a PCI graphics card is much faster than an integrated solution. For example, My i5-4690K CPU which is a fairly new processor has an Intel HD Graphics 4600 chip built in but you could argue that the GeForce 210, which is one of the cheapest Nvidia cards you can buy is better as it has a higher clock speed than my Intel chip but it isn't always that simple either as my Intel chip has 1.7GBs of Graphics memory while the GeForce only has 512MBs meaning it could bottleneck because it can't cache as much data.